# Adding space between words in a text box in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to do a little test in matplotlib by adding a text box in a plot. This step is already done but where I am struggling is when I want that my text inside has to be bold for the title and the second line without bold. In my example below, I am quite close to reach what I want but the problem is that my second line, there is no space between words where I want these spaces.

If anyone has a suggestion about it, I would be happy to try.
Thank you very much.

Here is the part of code I used at the moment and plot result is attached to this message:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

textstr = 'Greater Sample Size:\n$No. of Sites ≥ 3$'
props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=0.5)

ax.text(0.05, 0.95, textstr, transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=14, verticalalignment='top', bbox=props,fontweight="bold")

plt.show()
```

[Here is my test from the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9pWV.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the data inside the $ is not preserving spaces. You can use "\" before each space for the second line... So, change

```
textstr = 'Greater Sample Size:\n$No. of Sites ≥ 3$'
```

to

```
textstr = 'Greater Sample Size:\n $No.\ of\ Sites\ ≥\ 3$'
```

and you should get...

[image]

Comment: Hello Redox, thank you very much for your answer. It seems working and I got the same result as you. Thank you !.  What is exactly the role of the $ ?

Comment: The $ is used for mathematical expressions. Check [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html). As explained there, in your case, although the title is bold by default, using $ is removing the bold part and making it normal text.... more of a hack. So, you can use either `\ ` or `\/` to add a whitespace to the formula. Hope this helps